# Emacsclient not working

Tags: emacsclient

I have been using OS X forever. I have been using Emacs forever. I currently use the MacPorts Emacs.app and do `(server-start)` in my `.emacs` file. I can't get `emacsclient` going:

```
> which emacsclient
/opt/local/bin/emacsclient
>  emacsclient ~/.emacs
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

        --socket-name
        --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
        --altstrong texternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
```

Suggestions?

Comment: You might try `emacsclient --version` and compare that to the version of your `Emacs.app`.

Comment: Try running `emacsclient -ca ""`  The 'c' option tells emacs to open a new frame.  The 'a' option, when passed the empty string, will cause an instance of the daemon to be started if one is not already running.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to use `emacsclient` before having started the server.

You have `(server-start)` in your init file, but did you actually start Emacs normally before trying to use `emacsclient`?  If not, that's probably your problem: that call to `server-start` was not made before you invoked `emacsclient`.

An alternative is to use the `--daemon` command-line option when starting Emacs.

Node [Emacs Server](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html) of the Emacs manual explains it.

Comment: Guess I should have clarified that before trying to use `emacsclient` I open  Emacs.app, which has `(server-start)` in its init file. I have also tried executing `server-start`manually after Emacs is running, and it says "server restarted".

I am uncomfortable with the daemon approach because I use Emacs.app a lot and hardly ever try to use `emacsclient`, so even though it doesn't really matter, I would like to keep Emacs.app as the "primary" in this arrangement.